CSS rotate3d on a skewed ellipse - can't figure out
I'm trying to rotate an ellipse that is already rotated on a Y axis.
This is supposed to be an orbit around the planet that I want to put some elements on so it all rotates around the planet.
Here's the current code:


body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #01143D;
}

.galaxy {  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateX(75deg); 
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.planet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FB7209;
  transform: rotateX(-75deg);
}

.orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: -400px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotateY(-15deg);
  animation-name: orbit;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes orbit {
  0%   { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateZ(-360deg); }
}

.orbit .object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
<body>
  <div class="galaxy">
    <div class="planet">
    </div>
    <div class="orbit">
      <div class="object"></div> 
    </div>      
  </div>
</body>



The main issue is I want the orbit to be tilted (rotateY(-15deg)) and rotate it on the Z axis via the animation at the same time and these two cancel each other out. Rotate3d doesn't change anything, at least as far as I've  tried.
Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

You are right - the transform in the keyframes overwrites the transform in the element. Make sure all transforms that you want are present in the keyframes.

I managed to make it work by applying the rotateY to everything and it works well. A much harder problem that occurred is that it seems virtually impossible to determine they rotation values for the keyframes so that they object stays completely straight during the whole animation.
